# How to read a 30G parquet file by python

Tags: python-3.x, parquet, fastparquet

I am trying to read data from a large parquet file of 30G. My memory do not support default reading with ***fastparquet*** in python, so I do not know what I should do to lower the memory usage of the reading process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyarrow's [iter_batches](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html?highlight=parquet#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches) to read back chunks of rows incrementally.